# Is there a way to remove code from a Rails view before it is rendered in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicket

As the title says, is there a way to remove code from a view in a Rails app before it is sent to the browser (regardless of environment)?

For example: If I have commented code in a view and I want to keep it there for reference but do not want it sent to the browser.

As a reference, Apache Wicket can do this by wrapping the code in a `<wicket:remove>` tag. The code inside of that tag will never get delivered to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's commented out HTML you're worried about, simply wrap it in a false if statement:

```
<% if false %>
  <!-- this won't be sent to the client -->
  <p>nor will this</p>
<% end %>
```

or for smaller comments:

```
<% # my awesome comment %>
```

If it's Ruby code that's commented out, it won't ever be sent to the client.

(This all assumes you're using ERB, not HAML)